# BeautifulSoup: combine top-level text with classic tag find functionality?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract information from non-uniformly structured html blocks using BeautifulSoup. I'm looking for a way to combine text blocks sitting between tags in the output from my searches/filters. For instance, from the html:

```
<span>
    <strong>Description</strong>
    Section1
    <ul>
        <li>line1</li>
        <li>line2</li>
        <li>line3</li>
    </ul>
    <strong>Section2</strong>
    Content2    
</span>
```

I would like to create an output list that ignores certain types of tags (`ul` and `li` in the example above) but DOES capture top-level untagged text. The closest I've found is something like `.select(':not(ul,li)')` or `.find_all(['strong'])`, but neither of these can capture untagged top-level text simultaneously with the various target tags. Ideal behavior would be something like:

```
.find_all(['strong','UNTAGGED'])
```

producing output like:

```
[
<strong>Description</strong>,
Section1,
<strong>Section2</strong>,
Content2
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your output you could select the `<strong>` first and than its `next_sibling`.

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<span>
    <strong>Description</strong>
    Section1
    <ul>
        <li>line1</li>
        <li>line2</li>
        <li>line3</li>
    </ul>
    <strong>Section2</strong>
    Content2    
</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for e in soup.select('strong'):
    data.extend([e,e.next_sibling.strip()])

data
```

###### Output

```
[<strong>Description</strong>,
 'Section1',
 <strong>Section2</strong>,
 'Content2']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, <strong> followed by untagged text is not a guaranteed pattern. It could just as well be untagged text followed by <strong>

Comment: If there is no reliable pattern, it is difficult, especially because the connection to the exceptions is not clear from the OP. Can you provide a reference to the actual resource and specify more precisely what is expected as a result? does order matter? thank you.

Comment: There isn't one resource; this is part of data cleansing efforts on many html documents without a constant structure style. The overall purpose is to find certain section headers. Often times, these headers are contained within tags (<strong>Section2</strong> above), but sometimes they exist as free text. Maybe an alternative route could be to apply a function to tag untagged text, i.e. convert Section1 above to <p>Section1</p>.